# run javascript after updatepanel partial postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I have a JavaScript function in page header for changing visibility of stuffs in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    function toggleVis(id1, id2, id3) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id1).style.visibility;
        if (element == 'hidden') {
            document.getElementById(id1).style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById(id2).style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById(id3).style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(id1).style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById(id2).style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById(id3).style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }

// ]]>
</script>
```

It works when I use it in updatepanel with radio button:

```
<dx:ASPxRadioButton ID="RB1" CssClass="btnInline" runat="server" Text="Yes">
<ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="function(s, e) { toggleVis('Label33', 'textbox','Label34');}" />
</dx:ASPxRadioButton>
<dx:ASPxLabel ID="Label33" CssClass="btnInline" runat="server" Text="Label33" Style="visibility: hidden" />
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="textbox" CssClass="btnInline" runat="server" Style="visibility:hidden" Width="40px" />
<dx:ASPxLabel ID="Label34" CssClass="btnInline" runat="server" Text="Label34" Style="visibility: hidden" />
```

The problem is when I click a button for clearing the form, after that the javascript doesn't work by checking the radio button.
I have tried some stuffs that are in the internet, but I couldn't make it, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Use [add_endRequest()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383810(v=vs.100).aspx). Which will fire in partial callback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(toggleVis);
</script>
```

- Put above code in in `.aspx` page into `<head>` tag.
  Will work :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had tried it before but it doesn't work, don't you think that's because of using parameters like id1, id2, id3?!

Comment: Use `Jquery Change` event instead of  DevXpress `ClientSideEvents` Event.

Comment: Use this link which will show how to bind  RadioButton SelexctedIndexChange Event in jQuery - http://forums.asp.net/t/1734062.aspx?RadioButton+SelexctedIndexChange+Event+in+jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Prog is right, When page is partially post back your function will not be called. To make sure this will be call each time u have to call it like:
    window.onload = function () {toggleVis(id1, id2, id3);Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(toggleVis);};
function toggleVis(id1, id2, id3) {}

Comment: You both right, but I think the problem is how to write the code! thanks for your answer but it doesn't work, I also put code in a load() function and try to use it like <bodyonload="load();"> but it doesn't work too.